# Azure Data Factory copy day before data from slicestart date

Tags: azure-data-factory

can somebody let me know how to get previous days data i.e 2017-07-28 etc from my onpremises file system if my pipleline start and end dates are 
"start": "2017-07-29T00:00:00Z",
"end": "2017-08-03T00:00:00Z"

My pipeline's input is"FileSystemSource" and output is "AzureDataLakeStore". I have tried below JSON in my copy pipeline as input

"inputs": [

```
            {

                    "name": "OnPremisesFileInput2"

                         "startTime": "Date.AddDays(SliceStart, -1)", 

                         "endTime": "Date.AddDays(SliceEnd, -1)"

                }

            ]
```

I have also tried defining "offset" in the input and output datasets and in the pipeline as follows

"availability": {

```
        "frequency": "Day",

        "interval": 1,

        "offset": "-1.00:00:00",

        "style": "StartOfInterval"

    },
```

"scheduler": {

```
                "frequency": "Day",

                "interval": 1,

                "offset": "-1.00:00:00",

                "style": "StartOfInterval"

            },
```

none of the above seems to be working. Request someone to help me.

Comment: If you have the pipeline provisioned by day, just rerun the previous days time slice.

Comment: thanks Paul for replying, but I want the pipeline to pick previous days data from the time pipeline is scheduled to run

Answer (score 0):

I think a good strategy to do this is to think about yesterday's output as today's input. Azure Data Factory let's you run activities one after another in sequence using different data sources.

There's good documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-pipelines)

With an example like this:
[image]

Like this you can either have a temporary storage in between the two activities or use your main input data source but with a filter to get only yesterday's slice.

Answer (score 0):

Your offset should be positive.

```
"availability": {    
        "frequency": "Day",    
        "interval": 1,    
        "offset": "01:00:00",    
        "style": "EndOfInterval"    
    }
```

In this case it will run for example on September 7th at 1:00 AM UTC and will run the slice from Sep 6th 0:00 UTC to Sept 7th UTC. Which is yesterday slice.

Your input dataset should be configured to use the SliceStart for the naming of the file

```
"partitionedBy": [
                {
                    "name": "Slice",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": SliceStart",
                        "format": "yyyymmdd"
                    }
                }],
"typeProperties": {
      "fileName": "{slice}.csv",
```

}

It would look for 20170906.csv file when executed on Sept 7th.